# How to change image background with watermark in imageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert three images to one image.

> **pattern.png**(http://tap2search.com/images/pattern.png)
>   **shirt.png**(http://tap2search.com/images/shirt.png)
>   **logo.jpg**(http://tap2search.com/images/logo.jpg)

```
convert \( -size 500x500 tile:pattern.png \) \( shirt.png -alpha extract \) -compose copy_opacity -composite png:-
```

The above command compose first two images(pattern.png and shirt.png) and the result is [image].

But How can i put the logo.jpg as a watermark in the southeast side of the image.

Comment: Mmm, are you sure you want the background showing through around the neck of the shirt?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Actually this is the transparent image(shirt.png) so it's showing through around neck of the shirt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you want the watermark to show. So here are 3 variations. I am using IM 6.9.10.28 Q16 Mac OSX.

Black Watermark:

```
convert \( -size 500x500 tile:pattern.png \) \
\( shirt.png -channel a -negate +channel \
-fill white -colorize 100 \) \
-compose over -composite \
\( logo.jpg -resize 50x50 \
-negate -alpha copy \
-fill black -colorize 100 \) \
-gravity southeast \
-compose over \
-composite \
result1.png
```

[image]

White Watermark:

```
convert \( -size 500x500 tile:pattern.png \) \
\( shirt.png -channel a -negate +channel \
-fill white -colorize 100 \) \
-compose over -composite \
\( logo.jpg -resize 50x50 
-negate -alpha copy \
-fill white -colorize 100 \) \
-gravity southeast \
-compose over \
-composite \
result2.png
```

[image]

Partially transparent white:

```
convert \( -size 500x500 tile:pattern.png \) \
\( shirt.png -channel a -negate +channel \
-fill white -colorize 100 \) \
-compose over -composite \
\( logo.jpg -resize 50x50 \
-negate -alpha copy \
-fill white -colorize 100 \
-channel a -evaluate multiply 0.5 +channel \) \
-gravity southeast \
-compose over \
-composite \
result3.png
```

[image]

If you do not want the background to show through the tshirt, then do the following, for example, for the white logo.

```
convert \( -size 500x500 tile:pattern.png \) \
\( shirt.png -alpha extract -negate \
-alpha copy \
-channel a -threshold 0% +channel \) \
-compose over -composite \
\( logo.jpg -resize 50x50 \
-negate -alpha copy \
-fill white -colorize 100 \) \
-gravity southeast \
-compose over \
-composite \
result4.png
```

[image]

ADDITION: Regarding your new color PNG logo with transparency, try the following:

```
convert \( -size 500x500 tile:pattern.png \) \
\( shirt.png -alpha extract -negate \
-alpha copy \
-channel a -threshold 0% +channel \) \
-compose over -composite \
\( logo1.png -resize 50x50 \) \
-gravity southeast \
-compose over \
-composite \
result5.png
```

[image]

Comment: It working perfectly but when I applying the color logo as a watermark(http://tap2search.com/images/logo1.png) it's not visible perfectly. I want the original image as watermark.

Comment: `@ Jitendra Mohanta` See the addition to my answer.